# pgfplots - How can I print the y tick scale label only once in a groupplot?

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to have the tick label for the y-axis only printed *once* in a groupplot. This would be very useful for the case when one uses the following options:

```
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
```

Is this possible?

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{
groupplots,
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=4 by 4, %4 column(s), 4 row(s)
    horizontal sep=0cm,
    vertical sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
},
xlabel={Bla},
ylabel={Process},
%
every x tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(0.95,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt
},
every y tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(-0.05,0.99)},anchor=east,inner sep=0pt
},
scale ticks above exponent={2}
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(1,1200) (3,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2,1200) (4,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it (not) that simple or has it really been overlooked? :( Whether the label's position is adjusted or not, it looks quite awful when plots are grouped together like this. :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this was a bug which is solved in PGFPlots v1.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like an oversight in the `groupplots` library. The necessary change to fix this behaviour isn't complicated (it's just a single line), but it affects a very long internal macro.

To fix the library, put the following code in your preamble:

[image]

```
\makeatletter
%
% Determine the ticklabels of both x and y.
%
\def\pgfplots@group@determine@ticklabels{%
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{all}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{top}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPc{lower}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      % Do nothing as all should have xticklabels
    \fi
    \gdef\pgfplots@glob@TMPa{}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPb\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r1/.append style={xticklabel pos=upper}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@rows\relax
            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xticklabels={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@group@rows/.append style={xticklabel pos=lower}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@rows\relax
            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@rows
            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xticklabels={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
    % 
    % Defining styles for the ytick's
    % 
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{left}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPc{right}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      % Do nothing as all should have yticklabels
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPb\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c1r\pgfplots@row/.append style={yticklabel pos=left}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@columns\relax
            \foreach \pgfplots@column in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/yticklabels={}, /pgfplots/ytick scale label code/.code={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@group@columns r\pgfplots@row/.append style={yticklabel pos=right}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@columns\relax
            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@columns
            \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/yticklabels={}, /pgfplots/ytick scale label code/.code={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\pgfplots@glob@TMPa}
}
\makeatother
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\makeatletter
%
% Determine the ticklabels of both x and y.
%
\def\pgfplots@group@determine@ticklabels{%
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{all}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{top}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPc{lower}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      % Do nothing as all should have xticklabels
    \fi
    \gdef\pgfplots@glob@TMPa{}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPb\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r1/.append style={xticklabel pos=upper}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@rows\relax
            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xticklabels={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\pgfplots@group@xticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@group@rows/.append style={xticklabel pos=lower}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@rows\relax
            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@rows
            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xticklabels={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
    % 
    % Defining styles for the ytick's
    % 
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{left}
    \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPc{right}
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      % Do nothing as all should have yticklabels
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPb\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c1r\pgfplots@row/.append style={yticklabel pos=left}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@columns\relax
            \foreach \pgfplots@column in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@columns} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/yticklabels={}, /pgfplots/ytick scale label code/.code={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi
    \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\pgfplots@group@yticklabels%
      \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
          \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@group@columns r\pgfplots@row/.append style={yticklabel pos=right}}%
          \ifnum1<\pgfplots@group@columns\relax
            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@columns
            \foreach \pgfplots@column in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
                \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\expandafter{%
                    \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/yticklabels={}, /pgfplots/ytick scale label code/.code={}}}%
            }%
          \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\pgfplots@glob@TMPa}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=2 by 1, %4 column(s), 4 row(s)
    horizontal sep=0cm,
    vertical sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
},
xlabel={Bla},
ylabel={Process},
%
every x tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(0.95,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt
},
every y tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(-0.05,0.99)},anchor=east,inner sep=0pt
},
scale ticks above exponent={2}
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(1,1200) (3,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2,1200) (4,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only as a workaround: You can set the the `scaled y ticks=true` option for the left plot manually:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=4 by 4, %4 column(s), 4 row(s)% 
    horizontal sep=0cm,
    vertical sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
  },
  xlabel={Bla},
  ylabel={Process},
  %
  x tick scale label style={
    at={(0.95,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt
  },
  y tick scale label style={
    at={(-0.05,0.99)},anchor=east,inner sep=0pt,
  },
  scale ticks above exponent={2},
  scaled y ticks=false% <-
]
\nextgroupplot[scaled y ticks=true]% <-
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(1,1200) (3,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2,1200) (4,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there are additional problems in the groupplot: The tick position of the left and the right plot are different. The groupplot is wider then the `\linewidth`. There is not enough space for a 4x4 groupplot on the page. In addition I would insert a small horizontal sep between the two plots.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 2, %2 column(s), 2 row(s)% <-
    horizontal sep=5pt,
    vertical sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
  },
  width=.55\linewidth,% <-
  xlabel={Bla},
  ylabel={Process},
  %
  x tick scale label style={
    at={(0.95,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt
  },
  y tick scale label style={
    at={(-0.05,0.99)},anchor=east,inner sep=0pt,
  },
  ymin=400,ymax=1200,enlarge y limits=.1,% <-
  scale ticks above exponent={2},
  scaled y ticks=false% <-
]
\nextgroupplot[scaled y ticks=true]% <-
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(1,1200) (3,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2,1200) (4,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, these little details I overlooked sorry. Yeah the code was produced for the MWE only. Interesting bit about specifying the width that way.

Comment: In some cases, I need scaling for the x ticks though and this workaround will break. I'll edit the op in 5 minutes.

Comment: Um... never mind. Little error on my part, looked the wrong row in my actual, big groupplot.