# Interplay of description placement and units

Tags: pgfplots

The following minimal example of a group plot with units shows a problem (note the spurious `[m]` and `[s]` towards the center of the figure): It seems to me that `descriptions at` moves the regular text of a label but not the part that concerns units. Is this intentional, fixed in a more recent version than mine, or am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
xlabel = xlabel, x unit=m,
ylabel = ylabel, y unit=s,
group style={
    horizontal sep=0pt,
    vertical sep=0pt,
    group name=my plots,
    group size=2 by 2,
    x descriptions at=edge bottom,
    y descriptions at=edge left,
}]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: render]

List of packages:

```
 *File List*
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
pgfplots.sty    2015/01/31 v1.12 Data Visualization (1.12)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: See the answer to this question, does it help you? [pgfplots - How can I print the y tick scale label only once in a groupplot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200557/4778) Not sure if you want to remove the `m` and `s` from the center or do something else.